# Delayed GCM message not received on device

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developping an android app, and I have an issue with Google Cloud Messaging.

I've followed this tutorial http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html and I managed to send and received messages on my android device.
(I'm using gcm-node to send the messages).

```
        var registrationIds = [];
        registrationIds.push(success.key);
        var message = new gcm.Message();

        var message = new gcm.Message({
            delayWhileIdle: true,
            timeToLive: 3,
            data: {
                key1: 'message1',
                key2: 'message2'
            }
        });

        sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (err, result) {
            console.log("sent"+result);
            res.send(200 , result);
            return next();
        });
```

My problem is when I send a message with the device offline, when I switch it back on, I don't receive the message.

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the 'time to live' to 3 seconds. This means that after that time, it's deleted from the server. Leave that line out, the default time is several days. I can't remember exactly how many.